# Wall sliding in JavaScript; works, but gets stuck at corners

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, javascript, collision-avoidance, collision-prediction

this is a follow up to this other question: [How do I handle player collision with corners of a wall](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157267/how-do-i-handle-player-collision-with-corners-of-a-wall)

In inspiration of the code given in [its answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/160319/54454), I tried to write some new code.

Basically, in the original, the wall sliding works very well on the inside of the walls, but I wanted to make it work on the outside as well, so I made a new basic code engine, based on his technique:

```html
BH
<br>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<button onclick="start()" class=wow>ok</button>
<canvas id=can>

</canvas>
<style>
    canvas{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;  
        left:0px
    }

    .wow{
        float:right;
        z-index:1298737198
    }
</style>
<script>
    var aD =[]
    var r
    function start() {
        r = new CanvasRenderer(can),
            my = new scene();
        window.my = my
        eventHandler();

        my.add(new mesh({
            name:"ora",
            verts: [
                0,   0, //0,
                100, 15, //1,
                175, 40, 
                50, 100,
                20, 75,
                2,25
            ],
            position: {
                x: 100,
                y:100,
                z:1
            },
            scale: {

                x:1,y:1,z:1
            },
            color:"orange",
            onupdate(me) {
                if(!me.dx) {
                    me.dx=0//.3 
                }
                me.position.x+=me.dx

                me.position.y+=me.dx/3

                me.rotation.x+=me.dx*8*Math.PI/180

                if(me.position.x>=500) {
                    me.position.x--;
                    me.dx = -0.3
                }

                if(me.position.x<=0) {
                    me.position.x++
                    me.dx = 0.3
                }

            }
        }));



        my.add(new mesh({
            name:"tri",
            verts: [
                0,   0, //0,
                80, 35, //1,
                30, 70, 
                28, 30,
                5, 80,
                4,  30
            ],
            position: {
                x: 100,
                y:200,
                z:1
            },
            rotation:{
                x:-20*Math.PI/180
            },
            scale: {

                x:2,y:2,z:1
            },
            color:"yellow",
            onupdate(me) {
                if(!me.dx) {
                    me.dx=0//-0.2   
                }
                me.position.x+=me.dx

                me.position.y+=me.dx/3

                me.rotation.x+=me.dx*8*Math.PI/180

                if(me.position.x>=500) {
                    me.position.x--;
                    me.dx = -0.3
                }

                if(me.position.x<=0) {
                    me.position.x++
                    me.dx = 0.3
                }

            }
        }));

        var g = false
        my.add(new mesh({
            primitive:"rect",
            name: "player",
            scale: {
                x: 50,
                y:50
            },
            position: {
                x: 311,
                y:75,
                z:13
            },
            origin: {
                x:0.5,
                y:0.5,
                z:0.5
            },
            onupdate(me) {
                var upKey = keys[38],
                    downKey = keys[40],
                    rightKey = keys[39],
                    leftKey = keys[37],
                    drx  = 0,
                    dx = 0,
                    speed = 5,
                    turningSpeed = 3

                drx = leftKey ? -1 : rightKey ? 1 : 0
                forward = upKey ? 1 : downKey ? -1 : 0
                if(!window.aa)aa=me
                me.rotation.x += (
                    (drx * Math.PI / 180 * turningSpeed )
                )
                me.rotation.y = 1;

                var xDir = Math.cos(me.rotation.x)
                var yDir = Math.sin(me.rotation.x)

                me.position.x += xDir  * forward * speed
                me.position.y += yDir * forward * speed

                var lines = []
                for(var i = 0; i < my.objects.length; i++) {
                    let cur = my.objects[i];
                    if(cur.name !== me.name) {
                        cur.lineSegments.forEach(l => {
                            //if(lines.length>=2) return
                            var col = checkCollision(
                                me.position.x,
                                me.position.y,
                                me.position.z,
                                me.scale.x/2,
                                l
                            )

                            if(col) {

                                if(!me.curLine&&!col.iscorner)
                                    me.curLine = l
                            //  else
                                lines.push(l)

                            }
                         });
                    }
                }

                if(me.curLine) {
                    var oldL = lines.length
                    lines=insertAtArray(0,me.curLine,lines) 
                    //remove duplicates

                    lines = uniq(lines)
                    /*

                    old code remove curr


                    lines.filter((v,ind,ar)=>
                        ar.indexOf(v)==ind               
                    );
                    var sl = lines.slice(1)
                    var indo = sl.indexOf(me.curLine)
                    if(indo > -1)
                        lines.splice(indo,1)*/
                    //if(lines.length>=3) lines.splice(lines.length-1,1)
                }
                var fc = false
                lines.forEach(a=>{
                    var col = checkCollision(
                        me.position.x,
                        me.position.y,
                        me.position.z,
                        me.scale.x/2,
                        a
                    )
                    if(col) {
                        me.position.y = col.y
                        me.position.x = col.x
                        if(a==me.curLine)
                            fc=true
                    }

                })
                me.lines=lines
    //\
                if(!fc) me.curLine=null;





            }

        }));

        let i = setInterval(() => render(r, my), 16);
        r.on("resize", () => render(r, my));

    }

    function uniq(arr) {
        return arr.map(JSON.stringify)
            .filter(
                (el , i , arr)=> 
                i === arr.indexOf(el)
            ).map(JSON.parse)
    }

    function insertAtArray(at,val,array) {
        return array = array.slice(0,at).concat(val)
                .concat(array.slice(at))
    }



    function checkCollision(x1, y1, z1, rad,l) {
        var dist = distance2(
            l.start[0],
            l.start[1],

            l.end[0],
            l.end[1]
        ),
            vec1 = [
                x1 - l.start[0],
                y1 - l.start[1],
                z1 - l.start[2]
            ],

            vec2 = [
                l.end[0] - l.start[0],
                l.end[1] - l.start[1]
            ],

            percentOfWall = (
                Math.max(
                    0,
                    Math.min(
                        1, 
                        dot(
                            vec1[0],
                            vec1[1],

                            vec2[0],
                            vec2[1]
                        ) / dist
                    )
                )
            ),
            projection = [
                l.start[0] + percentOfWall * vec2[0],
                l.start[1] + percentOfWall * vec2[1],
            ],
            acDist = Math.sqrt(distance2(
                x1, y1,
                projection[0], projection[1]
            ))
        
        aD.push( () => {
            r.ctx.beginPath()
            r.ctx.fillStyle="green"
            r.ctx.arc(projection[0], projection[1], 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
            r.ctx.fill()
            r.ctx.closePath();
        })


        if(acDist < rad) {
            var mag = Math.sqrt(dist),
                delt = [
                    l.end[0] - l.start[0],
                    l.end[1] - l.start[1]
                ],
                normal = [
                    delt[0] / mag,
                    delt[1] / mag
                ]
            

            var x;
            var y;
            
            var iscorner=false
            if(
                percentOfWall == 0 || 
                percentOfWall == 1
                //case of corner[s]
             ) {
                
                var distFromProjToPlCenter = [
                    x1 - projection[0],
                    y1 - projection[1]
                ];

                var distNormalized = normalize(
                    distFromProjToPlCenter
                )

                var scaled = scaleVec(
                    distNormalized, rad 
                )
                x = projection[0]+scaled[0]
                y = projection[1]+scaled[1]
                iscorner=true
            } else {
                x = projection[0] + 
                    rad * (normal[1] )
                
                y = projection[1] + 
                    rad* (-normal[0] )
            }
            
            return {
                x,
                y,
                projection,
                normal,
                iscorner
            }
        }


    }


    function scaleVec(vec,sc) {
        return [
            vec[0]*sc,
            vec[1]*sc
        ]
    }

    function dot(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        return (
            x1 * x2 + y1 * y2
        )
    }

    function normalize(p) {
        var x = p[0]
        var y = p[1]
        //(x/(x^2 + y^2)^(1/2), y/(x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))
        var val = Math.sqrt(
            x * x +
            y * y
        )
        return [
            x / val,
            y / val
        ]
    }

    function distance2(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        let dx = (x1 - x2), dy = (y1 - y2);
        return (
            dx * dx + dy * dy
        );
    }

    function render(r,s) {
    //r.ctx.clearRect(0,0,r.ctx.canvas.width,r.ctx.canvas.height)
        s.update();
        r.render(s)
        aD.forEach(x=>x());
        aD = []
    }

    onload = start;

    function eventHandler() {
        window.keys = {};
        addEventListener("keyup" , e=> {
            keys[e.keyCode] = false;

        });

        addEventListener("keydown" , e=> {
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        });
    }

    function CanvasRenderer(dom) {
        if(!dom) dom = document.createElement("canvas");

        var events = {}, self = this;
        function rsz() {
            dom.width = dom.clientWidth;
            dom.height = dom.clientHeight;
            self.dispatchEvent("resize");
        }

        window.addEventListener("resize", rsz); 

        let ctx = dom.getContext("2d");

        function render(scene) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
            for(let i = 0; i < scene.objects.length; i++) {
                let o = scene.objects[i],
                    verts = o.realVerts;


                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(
                    verts[0] , 

                    verts[1]
                );
                verts.forEach((v, i, ar) => {
                    let y = i;



                    ctx.lineTo(
                        v[0] , 

                        v[1]
                    );

                });
                ctx.lineTo(
                    verts[0],
                    verts[1] 
                );
                ctx.fillStyle = o.color || "blue";
                ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                ctx.fill()
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
        }

        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            domElement: {
                get: () => dom
            },  
            ctx: {
                get: () => ctx
            },
            render: {
                get: () => render
            },
            on: {
                get: () => (nm, cb) => {
                    if(!events[nm]) {
                        events[nm] = [];
                    }
                    events[nm].push(data => {
                        if(typeof cb == "function") {
                            cb(data);
                        }
                    });
                }       
            },
            dispatchEvent: {
                get: () => (name, data) => {
                    if(events[name]) {
                        events[name].forEach(x => {
                            x(data);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        rsz();

    }

    function scene() {
        let objects = [];
        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            add: {
                get: () => obj => {
                    objects.push(obj);
                }
            },
            objects: {
                get: () => objects
            },
            update: {
                get: () => () => {              
                    objects.forEach(x => {
                        if(typeof x.update == "function") {
                            x.update();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
    }

    function mesh(data={}) {
        let verts = [],
            self = this,
            holder = {
                position:{},
                scale: {

                },
                rotation: {},
                origin:{}
            },
            actual = {

            },
            position = {},
            scale = {},
            rotation = {},
            origin = {},
            color,
            name,
            primitive,
            eventNames = "update",
            events = {},
            drawPrimitive = {
                circle(ctx) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(
                        self.position.x,
                        self.position.y,
                        5, 
                        0,
                        360 * Math.PI / 180
                    );
                    ctx.closePath();
                },
                rect(ctx) {
                    ctx.strokeRect(
                        self.position.x,
                        self.position.y,
                        30, 30
                    );
                }
            },
            width = 1,
            height = 1,
            primitiveToVerts = {
                rect: () =>  [
                        0, 0,
                        width , 0,
                        width, height,
                        0, height
                ]
            },
            realVerts = verts,
            lineSegments = [],
            o = this;

        function updateRealVerts() {

                let  actualVerts = [],
                    originedVerts = [],
                    adjustedVerts = [],
                    rotatedVerts = [],
                    stepSize = o.step || 2,
                    curVerts = [];

                o.verts.forEach((v, i) => {
                    curVerts.push(v);
                    if(
                        (i - 1) % stepSize === 0 &&
                        i !== 0
                    ) {
                        actualVerts.push(curVerts);
                        curVerts = [];
                    }
                });
                actualVerts = actualVerts.filter(x => x.length == stepSize);

                originedVerts = actualVerts.map(v => [
                    v[0] - o.origin.x,
                    v[1] - o.origin.y,
                    v[2] - o.origin.z
                ]);

                rotatedVerts = originedVerts.map(v => 
                    [

                        v[0] * Math.cos(o.rotation.x) - 
                        v[1] * Math.sin(o.rotation.x),

                        v[0] * Math.sin(o.rotation.x) + 
                        v[1] *Math.cos(o.rotation.x),
    v[2]
                    ]
                );

                adjustedVerts = rotatedVerts.map(v => 
                    [
                        v[0] * 
                        o.scale.x + 
                        o.position.x,

                        v[1] * 
                        o.scale.y + 
                        o.position.y,

                        v[2] * 
                        o.scale.z + 
                        o.position.z,
                    ]
                );

                realVerts = adjustedVerts;
                updateLineSegments();
        }   

        function updateLineSegments() {
                    let lines = [];
                    for(let i = 0, a = realVerts; i < a.length;i++) {
                        let start = [], end = []
                        if(i < a.length - 1) {
                            start = a[i];
                            end = a[i + 1];
                        } else {
                            start = a[i];
                            end = a[0];
                        }

                        lines.push({
                            start, end,
                            goof:o.name
                        })
                    }
                    lineSegments = lines;
        }
        Object.defineProperties(position, {
            x: {
                get: () => holder.position.x || 0,
                set: v => holder.position.x = v
            },
            y: {
                get: () => holder.position.y || 0,
                set: v => holder.position.y = v
            },
            z: {
                get: () => holder.position.z || 0,
                set: v => holder.position.z = v
            }
        });

        Object.defineProperties(scale, {
            x: {
                get: () => holder.scale.x || 1,
                set: v => holder.scale.x = v
            },
            y: {
                get: () => holder.scale.y || 1,
                set: v => holder.scale.y = v
            },
            z: {
                get: () => holder.scale.z || 1,
                set: v => holder.scale.z = v
            }
        });

        Object.defineProperties(rotation, {
            x: {
                get: () => holder.rotation.x || 0,
                set: v => holder.rotation.x = v
            },
            y: {
                get: () => holder.rotation.y || 0,
                set: v => holder.rotation.y = v
            },
            z: {
                get: () => holder.rotation.z || 0,
                set: v => holder.rotation.z = v
            }
        });

        Object.defineProperties(origin, {
            x: {
                get: () => holder.origin.x || 0,
                set: v => holder.origin.x = v
            },
            y: {
                get: () => holder.origin.y || 0,
                set: v => holder.origin.y = v
            },
            z: {
                get: () => holder.origin.z || 0,
                set: v => holder.origin.z = v
            }
        });


        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            verts: {
                get: ()=>verts,
                set(v) {
                    verts = v
                }
            },
            name: {
                get: ()=>name,
                set(v) {
                    name = v
                }
            },
            primitive: {
                get: ()=>primitive,
                set(v) {
                    primitive = v;
                    let newVerts = primitiveToVerts[v];
                    if(newVerts) {
                        this.verts = newVerts();
                    }
                }
            },
            width: {
                get: ()=>width,
                set(v) {
                    width = v
                }
            },
            height: {
                get: ()=>height,
                set(v) {
                    height = v
                }
            },
            position: {
                get: () => position,
                set: v => {
                    position.x = v.x || 0;
                    position.y = v.y || 0;
                    position.z = v.z || 0;
                }
            },
            scale: {
                get: () => scale,
                set: v => {
                    scale.x = v.x || v.x === 0 ? v.x : 1;
                    scale.y = v.y  || v.y === 0 ? v.y : 1;
                    scale.z = v.z  || v.z === 0 ? v.z : 1;
                }
            },
            rotation: {
                get: () => rotation,
                set: v => {
                    rotation.x = v.x || 0;
                    rotation.y = v.y || 0;
                    rotation.z = v.z || 0;
                }
            },
            origin: {
                get: () => origin,
                set: v => {
                    origin.x = v.x || 0;
                    origin.y = v.y || 0;
                    origin.z = v.z || 0;
                }
            },
            color: {
                get: () => color,
                set: v => {
                    color = v;
                }
            },
            realVerts: {
                get: () => realVerts
            },
            lineSegments: {
                get: () => lineSegments
            },
            update: {
                get: () => () => {
                    if(events["update"]) {
                        events.update.forEach(x => {
                            updateRealVerts();
                            x(this);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            on: {
                get: () => (nm, fnc) => {
                    if(!events[nm]) events[nm] = [];
                    events[nm].push(stuff => {
                        if(typeof fnc == "function") {
                            fnc(stuff);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        eventNames.split(" ").forEach(x => {
            var name = "on" + x;
            if(!this.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
                    get: () => events[name],
                    set(v) {
                        events[x] = [
                            data => {
                                typeof v == "function" && v(data)
                            }
                        ];
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        for(let k in data) {
            this[k] = data[k]
        }

        updateRealVerts();

    }
</script>
```

See "checkCollision" function and player loop for the relevant parts.

[Edit] It almost works as expected, but [as you can see in the following gif] it gets stuck only when caught between two objects, not sure why:

[image]

This version shows that the issue exists in any crevice, even within one object.

And either way if the angle is very small the player goes right through the corner:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this -- without using any kind of external libraries etc. (only what's available in the snippet)?

Comment: Being an effective coder consists of more than just taking other people's code and putting it into your codebase. You need to have broken down and studied the details of what Christoph gave you in 2018, and been able to build it up yourself again, step by step, with each step working in sequence. Keep getting more answers on the internet, and you'll get more lost and unable to work with your own code. Instead, you should be breaking down the code and asking the question for each function you don't grok, "What does this do? How does this work?"  In that way you may understand how to fix it.

Comment: @Engineer OK dude, if you would have looked at the quesions' code and this code, you will notice that they are almost completely different in every possible way. The only similar part is the collision detection, which I myself have been working for a very long time to perfect. Second, saying "don't ask questions on the internet" on an internet question and answer site, is not very befitting

Comment: P.S. the solution to your problem is hinted at right there in Christoph's answer, he points it out to you; did you sit down with a pen and paper and think about the geometric problem he broached with you? What did you discover?

Comment: @Engineer I didnt really take the method from christophers answer, since it didnt really work, I took it from the uathors own answer, which seemed to work (at least on the inside) but I don't think what he was saying relates to this oode, but even if it does I just need a working example to look at in order to understand it, right now I have nothing

Comment: OK. Do you understand the general principle behind why you are having problems at the outer corners and not the inner ones? This is key for you to be able to write your _own_ code this time, to solve the problem. So I'm going to be annoying and ask you questions, like a teacher would. The last thing you want is to still not understand the problem after this. If I just give you code, that may happen again.

Comment: @Engineer if you just give me code then I can see it working and analyze the code later

Comment: @Engineer but yes I get that the inner ones are different because its never actually colliding with a corner, its collidng with one point on each of the two sides, because since the cirlce has some radius, its impossible for it to collide with the atual corner on the inside, but on the outside, when it's x and y position (or velocity depending etc...) are set to the point of collision, it gets stuck at the corner becaause its actually setting the position to a single point, instead of just a combination of the two.. I just dont get how to fix it and make it keep sliding past

Comment: Right. One of the primary problems with this code is that the player has volume (a non-zero radius). The fact that it has a non-zero radius IS what is causing the corner problem. If that had been solved the correct way, there would no problem. So in the first place, you need to simplify the problem. Consider [this diagram](http://imgur.com/a/GakRqNv).

The black (positive radius) vs the red (zero radius i.e. only the line segment itself) - this is the effect your current code is producing. Which would be easier to use in starting to solve your problem? Black or red?

Comment: @Engineer I'm having a bit of trouble linking the above image to thiis  game, in the image, there are two rectangles colliding, in this game, although the player appears to be a square, but it is  in fact a circle that is doing the colliding, and the square is only a visual effect. So yes theoretically in the image it would be easier to check just line to line, not rectnagle-edge to rectangle-edge, but I thought that a circle only has one collision point anyways, so how would I apply that here?

Comment: Sure. I understand it may be difficult to visualise why this is the end effect. Just trust my experience on this - I've faced this problem over the years. What matters is that the moment you reduce the player's radius to zero, you will either eliminate the problem entirely, or cause it to happen less frequently and obviously (depends on how that code is written). The proposition here is that we start moving a player with zero radius first. And when that is working with just two walls (3 points) and one player, nothing else, we can then carefully advance to the next part of the solution.

Comment: What I'm trying to show you here is the distinction between the code that _has_ been written - which you are struggling to fix - and what we _should_ have written, and the _process_ followed in writing this new code.

Comment: You can also prove what I'm saying by making two adjacent walls run parallel (no angle between them). The moment they are parallel, you will either have the same problem on both sides where they join, or no problem on either side (again, depends on how that code is written).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107605/discussion-between-bluejayke-and-engineer).

Comment: It's past midnight here. Think about what's been said. You may begin to see solutions, or find sources online that can tell you more about these sorts of corner anomalies. Good luck.

Comment: Updated [diagram / exercise](https://imgur.com/a/0AxAIwp).

Comment: @Engineer Yes I undertand that the normals are the perpendicular lines for each edge, I didn't just blindly copy the code, and I get we have to push the player in the direction of the normal, and the amount we push back is how much the radius has passed the point of intersection, and I get that that would work if we had no width, I Just don't get what steps need to be taken when we *have* a radius

Comment: If you understand it all, then you should be good to solve it yourself. Have you sat down with a pen and paper like I suggested? Have you started writing a minimal test case to probe the problem for solutions?

Comment: @Engineer Yes I've done everyhting, are you going to provide an actual answer or just keep telling me how I don't understand it? Obviously if I understood it  I wouldn't have *asked* a question on StackOverflow. The same thing you're telling me, you can tell to **anyone** on SO, just "If you understood the problem, you wouldn't need to ask, therefor your question is invalid", but guess what, that itself is the reason why people ask questions on sites like this: to get answers, so jjust provide some actual useful piece of information other than "you don't understand the problem"

Answer (score 1):

You're not handling line endpoints correctly. Consider only a single line segment. The collision of a circle at the endpoint of a single line segment should be rounded, right? Like, if you trace out where the *center* of the circle should be stopped as you hit the endpoint from various angles, that will form a circle around the endpoint. Let's call this the player center's collision area. Now, you *are* correctly determining *when* the player's center has entered that area, but when it happens, you're using the same code to push the player away as you use when they hit the side of the line, which moves them to a point aligned with the line's endpoint, pushed out perpendicular to the line segment by the distance of their radius. This effectively pops them to the side of the line - to the same place regardless of where they touched the player center's collision area. If they've been sliding along the line segment and are trying to slide off the endpoint, this effectively pulls them back so they can't move forward (until they rotate to face totally away from the line). That's why you get stuck.

The solution is to change your collision resolution at the endpoints to push the player in the right direction: away from the endpoint. This is easy because you're already calculating the nearest point on the line and clamping it to the endpoints. So, instead of using the line's delta to calculate a normal vector to push them away, just take the direction from the closest point on the line ("projection" in your code) to the player's center ((x1,y1) - projection), normalize it and multiply that by the radius. This will always push them away, leaving them at the edge of the player's center collision area near where they entered it, so it won't pull them back as they try to round a corner. This will even work properly from both sides of the line segment.

Comment: even if it collides with mutliple lines at once, thus colliding with 2 separate corners [which are really the same point], this will still work?

Comment: It should, because both line endpoints are the same point, so pushing the player away from them should resolve to the same location for both lines.

Comment: Hi thanks I implemented what you suggested, but see the new edit, it looks like it kind of works, but since the player is still moving the same direction it was before it keeps re-hitting the wall

Comment: Also based on tests I've just run it appears that for some reason it makes a difference, pushing away from the point, depending on which direction it is colliding by [which is probably because that's the first collision resolved by the for loop], that it looks like it pushes it away from the direction of the line which the point is a part of, as u can see if u approach the line from different sides. Not sure why this is considering it's just one point

Comment: `x = x1+scaled[0]` should be `x = projection[0]+scaled[0]`. same with `y`, because `scaled` is an offset from the nearest point on the line, not from the player's current position. (Also, once it's working, you shouldn't even need the `percentOfWall` = 0 or 1 check, because this code should work for the sides too.)

Comment: Hi again thanks for the suggestion, it almost works perfectly! :) There's just one more issue that I added in a  new edit, for some reason when approaching it from the opposite side at a certain speed it appears to be stuck, but not if it approaches the wall from the other side, even with the same speed

Comment: Ohh, I think this *is* an issue with the order of the line segment checks. The player is moving into the wall a bit, gets pushed by the endpoint of the upper wall, which pushes it down a bit, then gets pushed out of the lower wall normally, but that little push down is making it hard to travel upward. That's going to be harder to fix. If you could always check the closer line segment first, that would probably fix it, but it's a big change. You could split your movement up into multiple smaller movements, and that would alleviate the issue somewhat. I'll think about it...

Comment: yo see edit i was able to get it to tell which side it hit first for 1 object but a similar problem of getting stuck at corners exists for multiple objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137674/discussion-between-john-haggerty-and-bh-biezras-boruch-hashem).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about javascript, but it seems like you are moving from pt1 to pt2 when you are colliding a wall. Notice that it depends what direction you are going. If you go on a wall and slide and block to the corner, when you go on the other wall sharing the same corner, you can slide and it will exit the wall, where on the other wall it was blocking. Now, if I get this right, you are sliding on the wall using pt1 to pt2, and it seems like depending on which corner is pt1 and which is pt2, you won't block on one of them. That means the order of the wall points changes something and somewhere you are saying that pt1 won't block and pt2 will block, or vice versa. If you understand any of this script, you should be able to fix this. Else, like the others said, you should try to understand it first, play around with it, than try to fix the problem.

Comment: The reason why it works for some and not others is because the order it loops through the line segments. But even for the side that "works", it's only if it's slid off from a very specific angle, but heading at it straight doesn't work. Tried taking out collision for corners altogether, nope. Tried continuing to slide based on previous motion, nope (jitters at very end, not smooth but technically is more than nothing). Tried pushing it back along a line perpendicular to the corner, but since the movement is still in the same direction, continuously towards it, created just more jittering